# sql find rows with different column values

Tags: mysql, sql-server

My database table is (it has millions of records)

```
    sitename        rank     date
    facebook.com    1       2016-2-13
    gmail.com       2       2016-2-13
    yahoo.com       3       2016-2-13
    aol.com         4       2016-2-13
    facebook.com    1       2016-2-14
    gmail.com       2       2016-2-14
    yahoo.com       4       2016-2-14
    aol.com         3       2016-2-14
```

I want to find sites whose ranking has changed.
in the above illustration yahoo and aol has changed. I tried several queries but cant get it to work.

Comment: something like this http://bit.ly/1SpK6Mj

Comment: please specify your question: changed since some date or ever

Comment: lets say changed over 1 month.

Comment: SQL SERVER or MYSQL? and look at my answer , should do the trick

Comment: even `top 1 with ties` with filter by date might satisfy your needs

Comment: @sagi yes i gave it a try but its only showing domains, i also want the change / difference. Look at the bit.ly link above.

Comment: @IvanStarostin top 1 with ties ? sorry didnt get you

Comment: Let's discuss queries you have tried. Probably the solution was very close. I guess at least it will make possible to identify all the details of your actual request.

Comment: @johnyyy i came to same solution as sagi

Comment: @johnyyy I think I got it :)

Comment: none of you have incorporated date (change over a month).

Answer (score 2):

Its a simple select, group by and having query like this:

```
SELECT sitename,MAX(rank) - MIN(rank) as changed
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY sitename
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rank) > 1
```

Comment: yeah, but if you run `select *`, the date will still be `2016-02-13`

Comment: i also want the change / difference. Look at the bit.ly link above. Any idea ?

Comment: I need to show date-wise change. By using Max() and Min() you arent taking account of date. There's no way to tell if change is negative or positive.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the ideas given, here's what I've got:

```
SELECT sitename, rank, rank - (SELECT rank from sites WHERE sitename = main.sitename ORDER BY date LIMIT 1,2) as rankChange
FROM sites as main
WHERE date <= NOW()
GROUP BY sitename
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rank) > 1
```

This will return

```
sitename    rank    rankChange
aol.com        4             1
yahoo.com      3            -1
```

If you remove `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rank) > 1` from the query, you will see the set with the unchanged webs:

```
sitename    rank    rankChange
aol.com        4             1
facebook.com   1             0
gmail.com      2             0
yahoo.com      3            -1
```

Comment: @johnyyy there's a whole chapter on that in mysql documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html   Sorry, but I can't generate millions of rows of mock data just to optimize this query for you.

Comment: is there any other way using max(date) and min(date) ?

Comment: @johnyyy I think this is an answer. How to optimize that is another question

Comment: @Ivan The query keeps loading, havent seen the result of this query

Comment: @johnny Have you made restrictions in where clause by date? I suppose you have a start and end date for which you want a change. In example there is no restriction in fact

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select sitename from table group by sitename having count(*) > 1 order by sitename, rank DESC
```

Comment: Now thats almost a copy of my answer, and still won't work since you are missing the distinct in the count which will results in returning every one that appeared twice or more on the table no matter if the rank changed. Also, order by in unnecessary .

Answer (score 0):

you can do by like this:

```
select * from your_table t_outer
group by sitename, date
having rank <> (select rank from your_table t_internal 
where t_outer.date > t_internal.date and t_outer.sitename = t_internal.sitename
order by t_internal.date limit 1)
```

and it is output:

[image]

Comment: @johnyyy it gives me the output in the picture I upload

Answer (score 0):

Something like following. And you need a record for every site every day

```
SELECT sitename, MAX(rank) - MIN(rank) as ChangeRank
FROM ChangeHistoryTable
WHERE date between dateFromWhichYouNeedChanges and dateToWhichYouNeedChanges
GROUP BY sitename
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rank) > 1
```

Comment: the result is both yahoo and aol show `-1` (if I use `now()`)

Comment: @Nordenheim Yes, I missundertstood the task. Then your answer is right